# Delphi interface implements

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-2007, implements

I would expect that the reference counting should work on the outer aggregating object in an interface implementation. 
If I can refer to another example: [Clarity in classes implementing multiple interfaces (alternative to delegation):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836425/clarity-in-classes-implementing-multiple-interfaces-alternative-to-delegation)

Here is a minimal reproduction of the behaviour:

```
program SO16210993;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  IFoo = interface
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TFooImpl = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TContainer = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
  private
    FFoo: IFoo;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Foo: IFoo read FFoo implements IFoo;
  end;

procedure TFooImpl.Foo;
begin
  Writeln('TFooImpl.Foo called');
end;

constructor TContainer.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FFoo := TFooImpl.Create;
end;

destructor TContainer.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln('TContainer.Destroy called');//this line never runs
  inherited;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  Foo : IFoo;
begin
  Foo := TContainer.Create;
  Foo.Foo;
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

If instead of using `implements`, I implement the interface in the `TImplementor` class then the destructor runs.

Comment: "Am I missing something?" I don't know. But we certainly are. You forgot to include the code! Full program that demonstrates behaviour is required. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: you have some extra references or reference loops. Add overrides for TFirstSecond._AddRef and TFirstSecond._Release and put breakpoints there, get a full list of references and see which ones were not cleared

Comment: Well, the issue is that your interfaces are delegated. Not sure why that causes this behaviour.

Comment: Good question. I took the liberty of producing a really simple demonstration test case.

Comment: The idea of delegation is a nice official feature in Delphi, but it appears not to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What is happening here is that you call `TContainer.Create` and create an instance to an object. But you then assign that instance to an interface reference, the global variable `Foo`. Because that variable is of type `IFoo`, the interface delegation means that the implementing object is the instance of `TFooImpl` and **not** the instance of `TContainer`.

Hence nothing ever takes a reference to the instance of `TContainer`, its reference count is never increased, and so it is never destroyed.

I don't think there's a very easy way around this. You may be able to use `TAggregatedObject` but it may not solve your problem. It would force you to declare `TContainer.FFoo` to be of type `TFooImpl` which I imagine you do not want to do. Anyhow, here's what it looks like re-cast that way:

```
program SO16210993_TAggregatedObject;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  IFoo = interface
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TFooImpl = class(TAggregatedObject, IFoo)
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TContainer = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
  private
    FFoo: TFooImpl;
    function GetFoo: IFoo;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Foo: IFoo read GetFoo implements IFoo;
  end;

procedure TFooImpl.Foo;
begin
  Writeln('TFooImpl.Foo called');
end;

destructor TContainer.Destroy;
begin
  Writeln('TContainer.Destroy called');//this line does run
  FFoo.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TContainer.GetFoo: IFoo;
begin
  if not Assigned(FFoo) then
    FFoo := TFooImpl.Create(Self);
  Result := FFoo;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  Foo : IFoo;
begin
  Foo := TContainer.Create;
  Foo.Foo;
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Implementing_Interfaces_by_Delegation_.28Win32_only.29) does talk about this:

> The class you use to implement the delegated interface should derive from TAggregationObject.

Initially I could not find any documentation for this `TAggregationObject`. And finally I realised that it's actually named `TAggregatedObject` and is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TAggregatedObject).

> TAggregatedObject provides the functionality for an inner object of an
>   aggregate by implementing the IInterface methods to delegate to the
>   controlling IInterface.
>
> An aggregated object is an object composed of several interfaced
>   objects. Each object implements its own behavior and interfaces, but
>   all the objects share the same reference count, which is that of the
>   controller object. In the container pattern, the controller is the
>   container object.
>
> TAggregatedObject does not itself support any interfaces. However, as
>   is typical of an aggregate, it does implement the methods of
>   IInterface, which are used by the objects that descend from it.
>   TAggregatedObject, therefore, serves as a base for classes that
>   implement interfaces for creating objects that are part of an
>   aggregate.
>
> TAggregatedObject is used as a base for classes that create contained
>   objects and connecting objects. Using TAggregatedObject ensures that
>   calls to the IInterface methods delegate to the controlling IInterface
>   of the aggregate.
>
> The controlling IInterface is specified in the constructor for
>   TAggregatedObject and is indicated by the Controller property.

In addition there is this from the source code comments:

> TAggregatedObject and TContainedObject are suitable base   classes
>   for interfaced objects intended to be aggregated   or contained in an
>   outer controlling object.  When using   the "implements" syntax on an
>   interface property in   an outer object class declaration, use these
>   types   to implement the inner object.
>
> Interfaces implemented by aggregated objects on behalf of   the
>   controller should not be distinguishable from other   interfaces
>   provided by the controller.  Aggregated objects   must not maintain
>   their own reference count - they must   have the same lifetime as
>   their controller.  To achieve this,   aggregated objects reflect the
>   reference count methods   to the controller.
>
> TAggregatedObject simply reflects QueryInterface calls to   its
>   controller.  From such an aggregated object, one can   obtain any
>   interface that the controller supports, and   only interfaces that the
>   controller supports.  This is   useful for implementing a controller
>   class that uses one   or more internal objects to implement the
>   interfaces declared   on the controller class.  Aggregation promotes
>   implementation   sharing across the object hierarchy.
>
> TAggregatedObject is what most aggregate objects should   inherit
>   from, especially when used in conjunction with   the "implements"
>   syntax.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo I found the docs in the end. There was a typo!!

Comment: I was mislead by the countless examples I found elsewhere. It makes perfect sense that the reference count has to take place somewhere. Thanks for answering

Comment: You are welcome. It was an interesting learning experience for me!

Comment: Marcos Santos came up with what it seems to me an elegant solution to allow an interface implementation to be used both as a regular object and as an aggregated object [link](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http%3A%2F%2Fobjectpascalprogramming.com%2Fposts%2Fobjetos-agregados%2F).
The solution is descending the implementation class from TInterfacedObject, so it can be used as a standalone object and a decorator descending from TAggregatedObject whenever the same implementation is to be used with the keyword implements.